# Google Play Store suddently began crashing every time I open it

Tags: android, crash, google-play, google-play-services

Suddently, during regular usage of my Nexus 5, the Google Play Store started crashing every time I try to open it.
So, I tried to get the log of the error, here it is:

```
11664-11664/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.android.vending, PID: 11664
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:334)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1605)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                   at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.getMySessions(IPackageInstaller.java:385)
                                                   at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.getMySessions(PackageInstaller.java:415)
                                                   at com.google.android.finsky.installer.PackageInstallerImpl.<init>(PackageInstallerImpl.java:71)
                                                   at com.google.android.finsky.installer.PackageInstallerFactory.init(PackageInstallerFactory.java:23)
                                                   at com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.onCreate(FinskyApp.java:387)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:334) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102) `
```

I tried to look for this error online, but couldn't find anything. I assume it's related to some system app that has one of her permissions unapproved (I don't know which could be the one), or maybe related to my Xposed Framework installation.

What could it be?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may try the workaround stated [here](https://www.androidpit.com/google-play-not-working). Try clearing the apps cache and data. If clearing the cache and data in your Google Play Store didn’t work then you may need to go into your Google Play Services and clear the data and cache there. You may also try to [install the latest version](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-iii/267335-google-play-store-crashing-everytime-i-pull-up.html) of Play Store.

Comment: Did you try to disable your xposed modules one by one until the problem disappears? It looks like some play store methods are being intercepted by one of your modules, which might be unwanted (/malicious) behavior.

Answer (score -2):

its not any other problem did you see Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(int, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. you have calling some null object reference.

Comment: The problem is that is an exception that Google Play Store is throwing in the second I open it. I cannot control of it's code.